# Transforming second order differential equation into the form of a hypergeometric differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hypergeometric-function

With what substitutions may an equation in the form of:

$x(1-x)^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+(1-x)^2\frac{dy}{dx}+kx=0$

Be transformed into a hypergeometric differential equation of the following form:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricDifferentialEquation.html

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have a typo and the equation you are looking at is
$$x(1-x)^{2}\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}+(1-x)^{2}\frac{dy}{dx}+ky=0$$
Because if it was $x(1-x)^{2}\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}+(1-x)^{2}\frac{dy}{dx}+kx=0$, then it is trivial (just let $g(x)=y'$ and use the integrating factor). So first of all let $\xi=x-1$, $y(x)=\xi^{\alpha}\eta(\xi)$
Then
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d\xi^{\alpha}\eta(\xi)}{d\xi}=\alpha\xi^{\alpha-1}\eta(\xi)+\xi^{\alpha}\frac{d\eta(\xi)}{d\xi}$$
$$\frac{d^{2}y}{d^{2}x}=\frac{d^{2}\xi^{\alpha}\eta(\xi)}{d^{2}\xi}=\alpha(\alpha-1)\xi^{\alpha-2}\eta(\xi)+2\alpha\xi^{\alpha-1}\frac{d\eta(\xi)}{d\xi}+\xi^{\alpha}\frac{d^{2}\eta(\xi)}{d\xi^{2}}$$
Thus the equation becomes
$$\xi^{2}(\xi+1)\frac{d^{2}\eta(\xi)}{d\xi^{2}}+\xi(2\alpha(\xi+1)+\xi)\frac{d\eta(\xi)}{d\xi}+(\alpha(\alpha-1)(\xi+1)+k)\eta(\xi)=0$$
Now, if $\alpha^{2}-\alpha+k=0$, the equation can be further devided by $\xi$, to yeild the hypergeometric equation, thus
$$\alpha=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4k}}{2}$$
And the equation becomes
$$\xi(\xi+1)\frac{d^{2}\eta(\xi)}{d\xi^{2}}+((2\alpha+1)\xi+2\alpha)\frac{d\eta(\xi)}{d\xi}-k\eta(\xi)=0$$
Comparing with the hypergeometric ode, we get
$$\eta(\xi)=_{2}F_{1}(a, b; c, -\xi)$$
Where
$$a+b=c=2\alpha$$
and
$$ab=-k$$

Comment: In the line after you expressed alpha in terms of k, for the term of the first derivative, why does the $\xi$ variable become $2\alpha$?